# Facebook Graph API PHP to make a comment to a post on a page as page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I'm using below code to post to my facebook page as page

```
$post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
```

I want to make a comment to the post I created. I don't know how to do that exactly. But based on some research, I tried below code and it didn't work.

```
$comment_id = $facebook->api("/$post_id/comments?message='This is m message'");
```

An **echo** or **print_r** for **$comment_id** doesn't return anything.

How can I accomplish it i.e. posting comment to a post on my Facebook page using Facebook graph API for PHP? Kindly guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you getting any errors ? Could you try doing the same on [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) with the value of token in your application and see if you get any error.

Comment: Can you guide me with what exactly to put in debugger? I'm a newbie in Facebook Development.

Comment: Echo out your Access Token from your PHP SDK using `getAccessToken()` , enter it in access token field, select the HTTP method as POST, and type end point as `/$post_id/comments` and type key value pair within it as `message` and `This is m message` and execute it. Also please try posting as the answer to your question and see if there is still any problem.

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/DeXaUXb9t51 I tried it in Graph API Explorer and it worked. But I can't get how to convert it to corresponding PHP Code.

Comment: As you can see it successfully created a comment below the post specified. I tried $comment_id = $facebook->api("/$post_id/comments",'post',array('access_token'  => $ACCESS_TOKEN,'message' => 'This is my message')); but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
$facebook ->api('/'.$post_id.'/comments', 
 'post', 
    array(
      'access_token' => $your_access_token_variable,
      'message' => 'Your message',
    )
);
```

Comment: $post_id returns an array and not a string which I supposed.
So the correct code, in my case, would be as follows:

    $comment_id = $facebook->api("/$post_id[id]/comments",'post',array('access_token' => $ACCESS_TOKEN,'message' => $message));

Comment: @SarthakPatel - Yeah need to pass access token along with message. Good Work !!

Comment: @Rikesh I am getting this error (#200) User must have accepted TOS do I also need to have a token of the user who is posting the comment ?